# fill array in list with zeros

Tags: python, numpy

I have this list:

`a = [ np.array([ 1,  2]), np.array([0])]`

I want to iterate:

`x = np.array([t[i] for i, t in enumerate(a)])`

but since `np.array([0])` has only one element, it will throw an error.

So, I thought to fill the `np.array([0])` with another one zero , and then

```
a = [ np.array([ 1,  2]), np.array([0,0])]
x = np.array([t[i] for i, t in enumerate(a)])
print(x)

[1 0]
```

So, I am finding the biggest length in the list:

```
temp = []
for i in a:
    temp.append(len(i))

themax = max(temp)
```

which is 2.  (the `np.array([1, 2])`.

Now, I must somehow fill the other subelements with zeros..

Note, that I will always have the zero  `np.array([0])` which causes the problem.

Comment: Maybe `np.empty()` is what you're looking for?

Comment: @Jan:No, I will have zeros in the list and i have to keep them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be to change your list comprehension to give a zero instead of an array element in the case of an array being too small:

```
x = np.asarray([(t[i] if i < t.shape[0] else 0.) for i, t in enumerate(a)])
```

This is more efficient as you don't have to expand all arrays with zeros.